# message: "createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string."

Tags: angular, validation, firebase-authentication

I have create signup form with firebase authentication.
    I have below code in which I have install firebase in my visual code editor
    then whenever I am submitting the form I get error

> message: createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.

I have checked the code using debugger ,it will show that email is undefined but  I will get password value.

So whenever these two values I am passing to authentication function it will throw the error message.
angular version:6.0 and firebase version:5.9.0

*signup.component.html*

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1">
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSignup(f)" #f="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Mail</label>
        <input type="email"
          name="email" id="email"
          ngModel
          class="form-control"
         />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input  
          class="form-control" 
          type="password" 
          id="password" 
          name="password" 
          ngModel
        />
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">SignUp</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

*signup.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html'
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private authService:AuthService){}
  ngOnInit(){}

 onSignup(form:NgForm)
 {
  const email = form.value.name;
   const password = form.value.password;
   this.authService.signupUser(email,password);
 }
}
```

And I have created authservice

```
import  * as firebase  from 'firebase/app';

export class AuthService
{
    signupUser(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
          )
      }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StakOverflow. I have 0 experience with Angular, but it seems to me `email` is not a valid input type. Or you haven't closed the tag. Or both.

Comment: You're passing `form.value.name;` as the email. Maybe it should be `form.value.email;`?

Comment: yes.. thanks.. I have almost forgotten that one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use binding to `ngModel` for values of `password` and `email` for a template driven form like so [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/message-createuserwithemailandpassword-failed-first-argument-em):

signup.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html'
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  emailVal: string;
  passwordVal: string;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService){}

  onSignup() {
    this.authService.signupUser(this.emailVal, this.passwordVal);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  ...
```

signup.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSignup()" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Mail</label>
      <input type="email"
        name="email" id="email"
        [ngModel]="emailVal"
        class="form-control"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input  
          class="form-control" 
          type="password" 
          id="password" 
          name="password" 
          [ngModel]="passwordVal"
       />
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">SignUp</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```